# how to rotate an SVG file 90 degrees?

Tags: vector-graphics, svg

I printed out a diagram from MATLAB and it's rotated 90 degrees clockwise from where it should be.

Is there software that can help me fix this and rotate an SVG file?

I tried tweaking the SVG manually using a `<g transform='rotate 90'>` element around the whole thing, but it doesn't handle the translation or bounding box correctly and I can't figure out how to get it right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Download and install [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), and then open the SVG file with Inkscape!

[image: icon]

> For my example, this will be our graphic:
>
> [image: before]

Now, to rotate the graphic `90` degrees clockwise, we can perform the following:

1. **Edit > Select All**

   [image: select all]

   [image: preview]
2. **Object > Group**

   [image: group]

   [image: preview]
3. **Object > Transform > Rotate**

   [image: transform]

   [image: rotate]

   [image: preview]
4. **Object > Ungroup**

   [image: ungroup]

   [image: after]
5. **File > Save**

Comment: that worked -- thank you! (already had inkscape; I didn't think it could handle svg automatically generated by other programs)

Comment: Well, if the SVG files are to [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), then Inkscape should be able to work with them! :)